# Has the Galactic Empire ever conducted large scale ground battles?

Tags: star-wars, warfare, empire

The Galactic Empire was at its prime after the end of the Clone Wars and prior to the Battle of Endor. The Battle of Jakku saw most of the Imperial Navy, Army & Stormtrooper Corps committed and wiped out.

I've seen only two mentions by an Imperial officer to "prepare for ground assault" so far: Agent Kallus to pursue Captain Rex and Darth Vader at the Battle of Hoth. Both times, the full deployment is just a handful of AT-ATs and whatever they can carry onboard.

From the rise of the Empire to before the Battle of Jakku, did the Empire conduct any large-scale ground assaults to the order of what is seen during the Clone Wars on any single planet - an actual war operation?

Please distinguish between canon and Legends.

Comment: Mickey Mouse canon? Jar-Jar canon? EU/Legends?

Comment: @DVK erm, I prefer Disney canon, though if you want to mention Legends as a part of the answer I'm ok too. I'm interested to know of specific instances where the Imperial army was fighting wars "just like the old days". But no, not interested in the Gungan Grand Army

Comment: A pity. Based on Episode I, it seemed to be more effective than pretty much anything anyone fielded.

Comment: It took Anakin to win a battle the Gungans are losing, and it took Ewoks to win a battle Vader is winning. I beg to differ.

Comment: I remember reading that Hoth was the first ever deployment of AT-ATs, previously I believe just the presence of a Star Destroyer in orbit was enough to quell unrest.

Comment: @Burgi In Legends, AT-ATs are already at full operational readiness for deployment as early as soon after Yavin. Luke wrecked one such walker factory. The game Rogue Squadron 1 was set between Yavin and Hoth, and faced plenty of walkers. In canon, it had been deployed as early as 2 BBY

Comment: I think you might be underselling Hoth a bit. There was also a significant troop deployment in addition to the AT-ATs. Unless you want to try to convince me that Darth Vader himself deployed down in an AT-AT and not a shuttle.

Comment: Is there anyway I can improve my answer?

Answer (score 7):

In canon, the Empire participated in several large-scale ground battles before the Battle of Jakku.

In 2 BBY, the Empire participated in [the Battle of Atollon](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Battle_of_Atollon?file=Capt._Rex%2C_Zeb_vs_AT-ATs.jpeg).

[image]

The Empire's ground-forces were composed of Stormtroopers, AT-DPs and AT-ATs.

In 0 BBY, the Empire fought in [the Battle of Scarif](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Battle_of_Scarif).

[image]

The Empire's ground-forces were composed of Stormtroopers, Shoretroopers, Death troopers and ACT-ATs.

In 0 ABY, the Empire waged [war against the ore-dukes of Shu-Torun](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/War_on_Shu-Torun).

[image]

It was comprised of multiple battles involving Stormtroopers, Magma troopers, battle droids and AT-ATs, as well as Shu-Torun loyalist forces that supported the Empire.

[The Siege of Inyusu Tor](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Siege_of_Inyusu_Tor) occurred in 3 ABY.

[image: Siege of Inyusu Tor]

The Empire's ground-forces were composed of Stormtroopers, Magma troopers, Imperial shock troopers, Jump troopers, Shadow Troopers, Viper probe droids
AT-STs and AT-ATs.

In 3 ABY, the Empire launched [an attack on the Rebel base on Hoth](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Battle_of_Hoth).

[image]

The Empire's ground-forces were composed of Stormtroopers, Snowtroopers, AT-ATs, AT-STs and Juggernaut Tanks.

In 5 ABY, the Empire defended itself against the New Republic in the Battle of Kuat Drive Yards.

[image]

The Empire's ground-forces were composed of AT-TEs, AT-ACTs, AT-ATs and AT-STs.

[The Battle of Jakku](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Battle_of_Jakku) also qualified as as a ground-battle partaken in by the Empire.

[image: The Battle of Jakku]

In this battle, the Empire's ground-forces were made up of AT-ATs, AT-STs, Stormtroopers and Sandtroopers.

There are too many Legends battle to list here, but they can be seen on [this Wookieepedia page](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Battles_of_the_Galactic_Civil_War).

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that there looks to be a big ground assault in Rogue One too with several AT-ATs.

Comment: @TheIronCheek I'll wait until the movie is out. Trailers can be deceiving.